# Manually fixed content jumps when scrolling with mouse wheel in FireFox, IE, Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, svg, mousewheel

I'm trying to stick some SVG elements position during scroll. But these elements are jumping when scrolling with mousewheel in FireFox, IE, Edge. Chrome seems fine. Here is the sample:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var rect = document.getElementById('rect');
container.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  rect.setAttribute(
    'transform',
    'translate(0,' + container.scrollTop + ')'
  );
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
svg {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg>
    <rect id="rect" x="0" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="red" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Looks like at first the scrolled content is rendered, and only then my position fix is rendered.